# vuex base state is shared between modules

Tags: vue.js, vuex, nuxt.js

I am using multiple vuex modules in nuxt store and I want to use the same base state in multiple modules like this:

```
// ~/utils/Sharedstore.js
export default {
  state: {
    byId: {},
    allIds: [],
  }
},

// ~store/entities/myEntity.js
import SharedStore from '~/utils/SharedStore';

export const state = () => ({ ...SharedStore.state });
```

But it doesn't work, whenever i mutate one state the state of all modules will be changed.

When I do this for all my modules it works:

```
// ~store/entities/myEntity.js
export const state = () => ({
  byId: {},
  allIds: [],
});
```

Problem is I would like to have the duplicated base states in one place (SharedStore.state). Why does it not work when importing and how can I fix it?

Answer (score 0):

I found a fix:

`export const state = () => JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(ModelStore.state));`

Need to deep clone the object using JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(obj)) instead of spreading.

I guess the contents of byId and allIds still get used by reference when spreading?